# The word for smoke left on walls or when an oil burns and the residue coats things. There's a word I can not place; it's like residual, but a noun

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Specifically when secondhand or thirdhand smoke creates a sticky or dingy layer on the walls and flat surfaces, usually it's due to the nicotine tar that's in the air. It leaves a layer on lampshades and curtains or causes them to yellow or brown and causes windows to become dirty or foggy until cleaned with a strong cleaner or alcohol.

I am looking for a specific word that I've heard that is not "thirdhand smoke" as my Google search keeps insisting. It is the creasote or film left when that smoke settles in a room. It is specifically used for cigarette and cigar burn residue. It is not limited to these specific events, just commonly used to describe what that layer is. Usually this film is sticky, found in older unkempt dwellings, has a strong odor and is tacky and thick. It's what causes smokers items to smell and if you were to open a smokeless ashtray or public ashing tower you would find it coating the entire interior because of the smoke that has been trapped and settled there.

It is not ashes, not thirdhand smoke because it is the film or residual layer that is left behind that later breakdown and become airborne particles that would be then thirdhand smoke (which only refers to the specific particulars derived from cigarette smoke that is embedded into the clothes or fabrics after it is handled and released onto the skin or into the breathing air as unhealthy and pungent smelling compounds).

My goal is to have a word for the mere layer or film or coating, not be of concern of it's effects, sources or future events. Please help me... Residual residue coating tar... Creosote, soot...it's similar to soot I believe.

Comment: You used [*residue*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/residue) in your question. I would have suggested that. Are you sure that's not what you want?

Comment: Some nice words here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/soot

Comment: Possibly a [patina](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patina).

Comment: Or perhaps the noun 'deposit', which is regularly used in relation to what smoke and chemicals leave behind.

Comment: I would have thought *[smoke stains](https://www.google.com/search?q=smoke+stains&tbm=isch)* was one of many possibilities. Often called *nicotine stains* though I suspect most of it is tar